# CentOS7.2にIntel® Media Server Studio 2017(Community Edition)をインストール

Tags: centos

CentOS7.2にIntel® Media Server Studio 2017をインストールしようとしています。

環境は以下の通りです。
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
$ arch
x86_64
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Aug 18 19:05:49 UTC 2016
```

1. アカウント登録
   https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-media-server-studio/try-buy
   にてアカウントを登録後、Intel Media Server Studio Community Editionをダウンロード(Linux版)
2. MediaServerStudioEssentials2017.tar.gzが入手できるので、以下のステップでインストール&リブート

   ```
   sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
   sudo yum -y install pciutils net-tools autoconf automake cmake freetype-devel gcc gcc-c++ git libtool make mercurial nasm pkgconfig zlib-devel mesa-dri-drivers wget bc
   sudo usermod -a -G video build
   su build
   tar zxvf MediaServerStudioEssentials2017.tar.gz
   cd MediaServerStudioEssentials2017
   tar zxvf SDK2017Production16.5.tar.gz
   cd SDK2017Production16.5/CentOS
   tar zxvf install_scripts_centos_16.5-55964.tar.gz
   su
   ./install_sdk_CentOS.sh
   reboot
   ```
3. リブートしたあとで、以下の通り確認をしました。

   ```
   cd MediaServerStudioEssentials2017/SDK2017Production16.5/CentOS
   tar zxvf MediaSamples_Linux_bin-16.5-55964.tar.gz
   cd MediaSamples_Linux_bin
   ./sample_multi_transcode -i::h264 ../content/test_stream.264 -o::h264 test_out.h264 -hw -la
   Multi Transcoding Sample Version 7.0.16053497

   error: failed to initialize VAAPI device
   ```

何か手順が違うのでしょうか？ Intel® Media Server Studioをインストールしたブログなどありますが、微妙にバージョンなど異なってどこが悪いのか全くわからない状況です。
ご存知の方、ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 質問に書かれてる `-a` は ハイフン が別のコード(別の文字) になってますが正しいでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。正しいオプション-laにしたところ、別のエラー（error: failed to initialize VAAPI device）が発生しました。対処法をご存知であれば何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `vainfo | grep -v 'unknown'` を実行すると 何と表示されますか？

Comment: error: can't connect to X server!
error: failed to initialize display　と表示されます。

Comment: X Serverは動いてますか？

Comment: OSはServerなのでXは動いていないと思います。動いていないとインストールできませんか？

Comment: Xについてのエラー以外は何か出力されませんでしたか？もし何も出てなければ libvaのビルドが失敗してるような気がします。`install_sdk_CentOS.sh` を実行した時にエラーなどなかったでしょうか。あとCPUの世代が古いのでそもそも対応してないかもしれません。https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/driver-support-matrix-for-media-sdk-and-opencl 新しいCPU環境でためしてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: Done.
Installation done.でエラーは発生していません。CPUは調べてみますがIntel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPUなのですが・・・

Comment: `Driver Support Matrix`を見ると`16.5 (Media Server Studio 2017)`は 第5,6世代 Intel Core (Broadwell/Skylake) をサポートとなってますね。3770は第3世代なので Media Server Studio 2015 がサポートしてると思います。

Comment: Note: 4
the Generation Core™ and earlier processors are not
supported by Media Server Studio 2017.と記載ありますね。失礼しました。2015で実施してみます。

Comment: i7-3930Kは第2世代の間違い？Driver Support Matrixを見つけようとしていますが見つからず。申し訳ありませんが教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 間違ったこと書きました・・・。たしかに3770は第2世代ですね・・・。

Comment: Driver Support Matrixが書いたページURLをご存知であれば教えてください。

Comment: 上のコメントに書いたurlに書かれてますよ。ただ第2世代は書かれてませんね…

Comment: 結論として、非対象のCPUだったとなりますね。残念。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is too old for IMS 2017

Comment: 本家Stack Overflowと違い、このスタック・オーバーフローでは日本語を用いてください。また、この質問は質問へのコメントの中で解決しているようですので、もしそこを見て回答なさったのであれば、[コミュニティwiki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)の仕組みを使って投稿することもできます。